# Performance of 32 bit application on 64 bit platform

Tags: performance, ubuntu, virtual-machine, 32bit-64bit

We have a 32 bit application. It is currently running on a 32 VM. If we run the application on a 64 bit OS(Virtual Machine) which supports Intel Virtualization Technology will it run faster? We do not have a 32 bit OS(Virtual Machine) which supports Intel Virtualization Technology.

There is not not enough material that I could find. Please share your knowledge.

Comment: And where's the problem that you are having with your code?

Comment: There is no problem with the code. with gcc-multilib support we can run 32 bit applications on 64 bit platform. But the question is on performance improvement with Intel Virtualization Technology.

Comment: Do you have **any** code or anything other than a question about performance of *something* on x86 and x64?

Comment: No. I do not need a code to be fixed.

Comment: Then you are asking in the wrong place. This website is meant to help you with problems/questions about code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

We were running on an instance which had no Hardware virtualization support. Now we tested on a new virtualized system with [Intel Virtualization Technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/virtualization/virtualization-technology/intel-virtualization-technology.html). The Application here is a 32 bit system and the new system was 64 bit OS - Ubuntu. This was run using gcc-multilib support for Ubuntu. There was not a huge performance improvement observed.